# Laravel Get All Messages between 2 Users from DB

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I work in an Simple message system between Users on my Site.

Every Message has an own `unique ID` soo every user can see only the `title` and `text` from the current Message. I dont want code now an chat Message system just want display all Messages above the current message between the 2 Users in an Table.

Example how my Message looks like now:

```
Title:
Text/Message:

Reply Button
```

I want display now above all other Messages.

Default code:

```
Message from <span class="font-weight-600">{{$message->From->username}}</span> sent to <span class="font-weight-600">{{$message->To->username}}</span>





<div align="middle" class="form-group">

<font color="#b7b7b7">





      </div>



      <div class="form-group">

        <label for="title">Subject:</label>

        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{{$message->title}}" class="formcreateproducttitle" readonly="">

      </div>

      <div class="form-group">

        <label for="text">Message:</label>

        <textarea name="text" class="formcreateproductdesc" style="resize:none" rows="8" cols="80" readonly="">{{$message->text}}</textarea>

      </div>

      <div class="form-group">

        <center>

        @if(Auth::user()->id == $message->To->id)

        <a href="{{route('sendmessage',['username'=>$message->From->username])}}" class="btn btn-primary">Reply</a>

        @elseif(Auth::user()->id == $message->From->id)

          <a href="{{route('sendmessage',['username'=>$message->To->username])}}" class="btn btn-primary">Send another message to {{$message->To->username}}</a>

        @endif

        </center>

      </div></font>
```

Code i want add before the default code:

```
<table class="table table-hover">

    <thead>

      <th>Title</th>
      <th>text</th>

    </thead>

    <tbody>


@foreach($message as $messages)
<tr>

          <td><?php $user = DB::table('messages')->where(['from'=> $message->from])->first(); echo $user->title; ?></td>
          <td> </td>

@endforeach  



        </tr>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

Controller:

```
 public function ViewMessage($uniqueid){
      $message = Message::where('uniqueid',$uniqueid)->first();
      if ($message == null) {
        return redirect()->route('messages');
      }

      if ($message->viewed == false && Auth::user()->id == $message->to) {
         $message->viewed = true;
         $message->save();
      }
      return view('message.view')->with([
         'message'=>$message
      ]);
    }
```

But now i see only the first Message between the users from DB in every Line, i think because `->first();` correct?

How i can Display all Messages between the 2 Users and not just the first?
Or from the Sender only how i have do it in the code above better from both.

Many Thanks

Comment: Do you have relationships set up?

Comment: You did it totally wrong, you should get all messeges in controller and then pass it to view.

Comment: You mean in my Controller: "$messages= Message::all(); " ?

Comment: I dont see your controller in code samples

Comment: Question updated.i added my Controller for View Messages. I know i must change this before now if its not work how i think it.

Answer (score 1):

with query builder:

```
public static function getAChatMessages($receiverUserId, $senderUserId)
   {
   $firstMessages = DB::tabel("message")->where([['from',$receiverUserId], 
       ['to',senderUserId]])->orderBy('dateTime','DESC')->get();
   $allMessages = DB::tabel("message")->where([['to',$receiverUserId], 
       ['from',senderUserId]])->union(firstMessages)->orderBy('dateTime','DESC')->get();
   return $allMessages();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

'first()' function will only return the first message, you need to change it with 'get()' and do the iteration on all the messages.

```
public function ViewMessage($uniqueid){
  //it will return a collection of messages
  $message = Message::where('uniqueid',$uniqueid)->get();
  if ($message == null) {
    return redirect()->route('messages');
  }

  //use loop to check on every message
  foreach ($message as $m) {
      if ($m->viewed == false && Auth::user()->id == $m->to) {
         $m->viewed = true;
         $m->save();
      }
  }

  return view('message.view')->with([
     'message'=>$message
  ]);
}
```